# Search doesn't return result for multiple keyword

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any other way that i can search for multiple string in a column without it having the FULLTEXT. When i added the MATCH and AGAINST to my sql, i get this error "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list"
Below is my code:

`$query = "SELECT id, title, introtext, published FROM`jos_k2_items`WHERE MATCH(title,introtext) AGAINST('".$search."') LIMIT 30";`

Comment: You need to look at how MATCH...AGAINST is used. [Full-text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you add a fulltext index on those two fields, of you're in for a *LOT* of preprocessing/dynamic query building:

```
... WHERE title LIKE '%word1%' OR title LIKE '%word2' OR title LIKE ...
      OR introtext LIKE '%word1%' OR introtext LIKE '%word2%' ...
```

Comment: Thanks alot @MarcB. What i did was to explode the string and pick the first two words and insert it like your example.